# Apply D3 tooltip to Donut Multiples

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jquery-tooltip

I have code like this that creates multiple D3 donut multiples.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

svg {
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.arc {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var radius = 74,
    padding = 10;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(radius - 30);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) {
      return {name: name, population: +d[name]};
    });
  });

  var legend = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("width", radius * 2)
      .attr("height", radius * 2)
    .selectAll("g")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(".pie")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("class", "pie")
      .attr("width", radius * 2)
      .attr("height", radius * 2)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

  svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(function(d) { return pie(d.ages); })
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "arc")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); });

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.State; });

});

</script>
```

I am looking for a way to implement the D3 tooltip so that I can see the exact data of each chunk of the donut when I put my cursor over it. I understand that there are other examples of the tooltip on here but none of them have worked with the donut multiples example.

Here is some example data

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
AL,310504,552339,259034,450818,1231572,1215966,641667
AK,52083,85640,42153,74257,198724,183159,50277
AZ,515910,828669,362642,601943,1804762,1523681,862573
AR,202070,343207,157204,264160,754420,727124,407205
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
CO,358280,587154,261701,466194,1464939,1290094,511094
CT,211637,403658,196918,325110,916955,968967,478007
DE,59319,99496,47414,84464,230183,230528,121688
DC,36352,50439,25225,75569,193557,140043,70648
FL,1140516,1938695,925060,1607297,4782119,4746856,3187797
GA,740521,1250460,557860,919876,2846985,2389018,981024
HI,87207,134025,64011,124834,356237,331817,190067
ID,121746,201192,89702,147606,406247,375173,182150
IL,894368,1558919,725973,1311479,3596343,3239173,1575308
IN,443089,780199,361393,605863,1724528,1647881,813839
IA,201321,345409,165883,306398,750505,788485,444554
KS,202529,342134,155822,293114,728166,713663,366706
KY,284601,493536,229927,381394,1179637,1134283,565867
LA,310716,542341,254916,471275,1162463,1128771,540314
ME,71459,133656,69752,112682,331809,397911,199187
MD,371787,651923,316873,543470,1556225,1513754,679565
```

The D3 doc of this can be found at 
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say "the D3 tooltip", because d3 doesn't have any built-in tooltip functionality. That said, there are some good third-party plugins out there for doing tooltips in d3.

[`d3-tip`](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) is one that would work well for what you're trying to do.

You can create a tooltip function to display your population data for each arc like this:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .html(function(d) { return d.data.population; })
  .direction('s');
```

Then you can call the function on your svg selection:

```
svg.call(tip);
```

Finally, you can use mouse event listeners on your arcs to show and hide the tooltip:

```
svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(function(d) { return pie(d.ages); })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.name); })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

Here's a [**PLUNK**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ts44B1mYegcde90gbMRr?p=preview) with a working example.

You can also check up on the d3-tip documentation [here](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/docs/index.md).

Comment: That looks great thanks @jshanley! Just one more question. Should I be able to use this within a function? I have a search bar currently that searches the states in the dataset and I cannot seem to get both to work now so I am wondering if it is possible?

Comment: I get a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: It occurs on the svg.call(tip); line

Comment: You should be able to use it in a function. Maybe you could post the code for the function you're trying to use it in so we can try to work it out. As for the error you're getting, make sure that your variable `svg` is a d3 selection, not the element itself. The `.call()` method applies to d3 selections, and if `svg` isn't a d3 selection, the property `.call` will be undefined and therefore calling `.call()` as a function will throw the error that you got.

Comment: Actually, it could also be that the variable `tip` isn't defined in your current scope, since it will be called as a function. Post some more of your updated code and we can try to diagnose it.

Comment: The function is used with a search bar

Comment: I have figured out that my problem is calling d3.tip() as my browser will not recognize it as a function. any ideas?

Comment: Did you link to the script for d3-tip? It's a separate file. What do you get when you `console.log(typeof d3.tip)`?

Comment: I figured it out. Simple mistake, I called the tip library before the D3 one!

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same TypeError while debugging my javascript code using d3js while adding tooltip for my barcharts.

```
 bars.append('rect')
       .attr('y', maxHeight)
       .attr('height', 0)
       .attr('width', function (d) { return x.rangeBand(d) - 1; })
       .attr('class', 'bar')
       .transition().duration(1500)
       .attr('y', function (d, i) { return y(d.y); })
       .attr('height', function (d, i) { return maxHeight - y(d.y); });
       .on('mouseover', tip.show)
       .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

In the above code i used ".on('mouseover', tip.show)" on "bars.append()".This is wrong usage.

Later, i found that ".on('mouseover', tip.show)" should be applied on function ".select('rect') or .selectall('rect')". 
Now below snippet is working correctly for my application.

```js
 bars.append('rect')
       .attr('y', maxHeight)
       .attr('height', 0)
       .attr('width', function (d) { return    x.rangeBand(d) - 1; })
       .attr('class', 'bar')
       .transition().duration(1500)
       .attr('y', function (d, i) { return y(d.y); })
       .attr('height', function (d, i) { return    maxHeight - y(d.y); });

  bars.select('rect')
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```